# After some of my additions, the fingers on the Rigify rig stopped bending

Tags: rigging, rigify

My fingers really stopped bending from scaling the controller.

[image]

Everything else works fine and even if I just rotate the controller with some finger, it rotates as it should. But not bending.

[image]

I compared the constraints on the hand bones (including the fingers) with the constraints of a newly created, pure and innocent rig. And everything seems to be identical. (Although the human factor is not excluded).

The only time I touched these bones was when I gave them a roll. In my past experience, this roll is correct and there were no problems with it.

**List of what I generally touched in this rig:**

- I heavily edited the face rig. (I don’t see the point in going into more detail about this).
- I gave the roll to my arms, fingers, and legs.
- And I added two deform bones in the buttock area.

[Source file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BdZnmFtU51vtYkTdtlHbvbXkH91wuRLB/view?usp=drive_link)

Blender Version: LTS 3.6